# Why is laravel not generating detailed code?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am following a tutorial and from what I'm reading `php artisan controller:make OrdersController` gives

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class Hello extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }}
```

However in my case I'm only getting:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Hello extends Controller
{
    //
}
```

I don't get the included methods and my boiler plate is clearly not as detailed. I'm using the same command `php artisan make:controller Hello`.  What could I be doing wrong? If it helps I'm on OSX.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first class is a resource controller, read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers)

If you want an explenation regarding an artisan command add **help** before the command:

```
php artisan help make:cotroller
```

you can see the options (**-r** for resource) to make a resource controller.

You can **manually delete** the generated controller and rerun the appropriate command:

```
php artisan make:controller Hello -r
```

Don't forget to add the route in your `resources/web.php` file

Comment: Thank you this was helpful.

Comment: Glad to help, happy coding